# Application loader iOS issue

Tags: ios, macos

My issue is that I am working on Mac OS 10.7.2 and my application loader is with version 1.3. Now I need to upgrade to latest version, but I could not get a single link to download the latest version of the Application Loader. How to upgrade to latest version of Application and also how to remove the older copy?

Comment: Do you still need application loader? I just archive the project in Xcode (4.2), share it to get an .ipa file, then upload that into the iTunes connect website.

Comment: the thing is my company is making apps both in iOS and in air iOS and then need to upload all the apps in iTunes, so I have to use application loader for the same, as I cannot use Xcode for Air IOS apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application Loader is included as part of Xcode developer tools.  Since you are on Lion you should be using the latest version of Xcode 4... look in /Developer/Applications/Utilities.

You can also download it from Apple.  I'm not sure whether we are permitted to share links to it, and in any event the URL can change, so I will simply direct you as follows:

1. Log in to itunesconnect.apple.com
2. Go to "Manage Your Applications"
3. There is a "Download Application Loader" link at the bottom of the page.

Though you really ought to look at submitting through the Xcode organizer build/archive/submit functionality; I find that it works better.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Can you help me with my other issue that do i need to uninstall the older version of application loader,if yes, what is the way to deal with the same?

Comment: First thing's first: can you just use the version bundled with Xcode?  Then you don't have to worry about uninstalling anything.

Comment: I am able to use the same version successfully, the only thing was I needed to upgrade it with the newer one. So should i assume that I don't need to uninstall it,right?

Comment: I wouldn't think so... you can probably install the new one in, e.g., /Applications.  But you said you are using 1.3.  That's WAY older than the one in my Xcode package.  Are you sure you are running the latest Xcode developer tools?

Comment: Yes I am using Xcode 4.1, I don't know why such an older version is shown in my macbook..!! Also I would like to thank you for the help. It worked for me.. :)

Comment: Xcode 4.1 is not the latest version... I am running 4.2.1.  4.1 has not been current since October.  This might be why you have an old Application Loader.

Comment: Thank you.. Also I will shift to 4.2.1 soon.. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Step: 1 -** go to "https://github.com/misterwell/MMMaterialDesignSpinner"

**Step: 2 -** Install : pod "MMMaterialDesignSpinner" & import in VC

**Step: 3 -** inside AppDelegate

```
var spinnerView: MMMaterialDesignSpinner = MMMaterialDesignSpinner()
```

**Step: 4 -** inside AppDelegate [didFinishLaunchingWithOptions]

```
let spinnerView:MMMaterialDesignSpinner = MMMaterialDesignSpinner(frame: CGRect.zero)
    spinnerView.frame = CGRect.zero

    self.spinnerView = spinnerView

    spinnerView.lineWidth = 2;
    spinnerView.tintColor =  RGB(r: 218, g: 28, b: 56)

    self.spinnerView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60);
    self.spinnerView.center = CGPoint(x: self.window!.bounds.midX, y: self.window!.bounds.midY);
```

**Step: 5 -** inside AppDelegate Declare functions:

```
//MARK:- ~~~~~~~~~~HUD Method
func ShowSpinnerView()
{
    // show Progress bar
    self.window!.addSubview(self.spinnerView)
    self.window!.isUserInteractionEnabled=false

    spinnerView.isHidden = false
    spinnerView.startAnimating()
}
func HideSpinnerView()
{
    // hide Progress bar
    self.window!.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
    spinnerView.isHidden = true
    spinnerView.stopAnimating()
}
```

> inSide AppDelegate

```
  class func sharedInstance() -> (AppDelegate)
{
    let sharedinstance = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return sharedinstance
}
```