# Xcode 8, Application loader not found in itunesconnect

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect, xcode8, macos-sierra

I am using Xcode 8.0 and application loader version 3.0. i need to download or update the latest application loader for ipa uploading. This link: [Application loader iOS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061110/application-loader-ios-issue) describe to go to "Manage Your Applications" tab/menu to download latest version of application loader.

Currently i don't see any tab/menu with name "Manage Your Applications".

How/Where i can download this ? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Application Loader is part of Xcode. You can download Xcode directly from the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12).

https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Application%20Loader_Overview#64343664

http://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/

Comment: yes, download latest xcode to get application loader